# Can ServerName match wildcards in the middle of a domain?

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver

I'm trying to setup a server with two `VirtualHost` records like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/dir/
    SetEnv FLAG false
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.*.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/dir/
    SetEnv FLAG true
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like the domain `sub.domain.com` to go through the first `VirtualHost` and a domain such as `sub.test.domain.com` to go through the second.

At the moment, the FLAG environment variable is always set to false, suggesting that `sub.test.domain.com` doesn't match the second one and so reverts to the first.

The only thing I can see being a problem is that the wildcard in the second `ServerName` directive is in the middle of the domain. Is this allowed or is something else the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be able to use wildcards in `ServerName`, use `ServerAlias` instead.